# bounties; accepted answer automatically gives the +50?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I had a bounty on a question almost expire, because I accepted an answer, and I saw a little light blue +50 underneath the accepted check arrow. I assumed the bounty was awarded due to my acceptance and the +50. I didn't know I didn't award the bounty until I received a "about to expire message". I'm glad I just happened to log in today.

To me, accepting an answer says "this solved my problem", so I would vote that when a question with a bounty receives an answer that is later accepted by the OP, the bounty should be automatically awarded instead of expiring. I know there is some auto-award, but I believe it is only half of the bounty.

Maybe this can be solved by making the icon more clear, i.e., changing the icon from light blue to dark blue is not very obvious to me. That is, it wasn't obvious to me that I had to do anything to give the bounty.

Comment: What if the bounty is given after the fact, by another user?

Comment: No worries, it would have been auto-awarded at the end: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty "*If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.*"

Comment: Admittedly, the privilige-page says something different http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties "*If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.*" Thus I posted a FR: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302640