# Clarifying bounty auto-award-mechanics in the help-center

Tags: feature-request, bounty, help-center

Currently, there are three pages in the help-center mentioning how bounties are auto-awarded.
Imho, all three would benefit from some rewording:

1. [Reputation & Moderation > What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)
   It currently reads:

   > #### How is a bounty awarded?
   >
   > The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration
   >   of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of
   >   24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award
   >   icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the
   >   answerer. (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)
   >
   > If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
   >   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
   >   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or
   >   more eligible answers have the same score (i.e., their scores are
   >   tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty. If there's no answer
   >   meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.
   >
   > If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question
   >   owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the
   >   bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty
   >   owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty
   >   amount at the time of bounty expiration.
   >
   > As a special bonus, any reputation you earn from being awarded a
   >   bounty is exempt from the daily reputation cap.

   I suggest replacing the middle two paragraphs with:

   > For bounties you offer on your own questions, if you forget to award the bounty but you accepted an answer posted during the bounty-period, we assume you wanted to select that one and do it for you.
   >   Otherwise, the highest-voted answer scoring at least 2 which was posted during the bounty-period, ties broken in favor of the oldest candidate, will be awarded half the bounty.
   >   If that also fails, the bounty is simply gone without being awarded.

   Which has the advantages of being shorter, easier to understand and puts the possibilities in the right order.
   <sub>Further refined with help from [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/15498)</sub>
2. [Reputation & Moderation > What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):
   The relevant part reads:

   > You gain reputation when:
   >
   > - [...]
   > - bounty awarded to your answer: + full bounty amount
   > - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: + half of the bounty amount ([see more details about how bounties
   >     work](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/bounty))
   > - [...]

   I suggest changing the auto-award point by inserting "mostly":

   > - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: + half of the bounty amount (mostly, [see more details about how bounties
   >     work](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/bounty))
3. [Privileges > set bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)
   The relevant paragraph is:

   > If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period
   >   ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top
   >   voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of
   >   at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation
   >   will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be
   >   lost forever.

   Which is simply wrong. Duplicating the "What is a bounty"-page, or just linking to it there are two options.
   The problem is simply said that those two pages cover the same ground and don't acknowledge each others existence.

Comment: Maybe the slightly longer "For bounties you create on your own questions, if you forget to award the bounty but you accepted an answer posted during the bounty-period, we assume you wanted to select that one and do it for you.".

Comment: That works. Just substituting "offer" for "create" and editing that in. Thanks.

Comment: I think the subclause about the ties should be put in parenthesis, to simplify parsing the sentence. Or if you don't like parens, make it an extra sentence: "*… bounty. Ties are broken in favor of the oldest candidate.*"

Comment: I see absolutely no reason for inserting the "*mostly*".